# jquery show() and hide()

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a div:

```
<div class="showHide">
    //content
</div>
```

and a button

```
<button id="event" class="show" type="button">Show more news</button>
```

css is:

```
.showHide {
   display: none;
 }
```

here jquery:

```
function show() {
    $(".show").click(function(){
    $(".hideShow").show(500,'linear');
    $(".show").replaceWith('<button id="event" class="hide" type="button">Show less news</button>');
});
}
function hide() {
    $(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".hideShow").hide(500, 'linear');
    $(".hide").replaceWith('<button id="event" class="show" type="button">Show more news</button>');
});
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   show();
   hide();
});
```

When I click first time the script show the div and replace the button, but when I click second time to hide the script doesn't work..any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider rewriting it a bit:

```
$('#event').on('click', function() {
    // Using toggle to switch between hidden/shown
    $('.showHide').toggle(500);

    // Replace text on button
    var buttonText =  ($('.showHide').is(":visible") == true) ? "Show less news" : "Show more news";
    $('#event').text(buttonText);
});
```

Basically I register a click event on the button. When its clicked the div with the content toggles between visible and hidden. After that the text on the button is exchanged to a more suitable one.

Comment: wooow!!! It works!! thank you very much..maybe I need to study some javascript!! :)

Comment: I saw a bug...when the content is hide the text of the button doesn't change..it remains "Show less news"...I replaced the button text putting an if that control the text and change it in case..it works...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the button does not exists anymore where you did bind your events to. So you can create a new button and add an event handler to it. Or change the inputs text and have 1 handler like:

```
$(function(){ // Document ready
    $(".showhidebtn").click(function(){
        $(".hideShow").toggle(500, 'linear');
        if( $(".hideShow").is(":visible") ) {
            $(this).val("Hide element"); // Don't know if you need to use `val()` or `html()`.
        } else {
            $(this).val("Show element");
        }
    });
});
```